# XSLT Return variable from Template

Tags: xml, xslt

So I have been given something to fix and I have a limited knowledge of XSLT. I essentially want to retain a variable from a template I run.

```
<xsl:template name="repeatable">
  <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
  <xsl:param name="total" select="10" />

  <xsl:if test="not($index = $total)">
      <xsl:call-template name="repeatable">
          <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

The above is a template that I want to return the variable "$total" from. The below template is the template that I call the above template from.

```
<xsl:template match="randomtemplate">
    <xsl:call-template name="repeatable" \>
</xsl:template>
```

So essentially, I just want to get the "total" variable returned to me or in some way accessible from randomtemplate.

Cheers

Comment: I am afraid this makes no sense. The value of the $total parameter is 10. That's hard-coded into the stylesheet, and it's not going to change, unless *you* change it.

Answer (score 3):

This may not actually be what you actually need, but what you can do is change the `repeatable` template to simply output a value when the total is reached, like so:

```
  <xsl:template name="repeatable">
    <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="total" select="10" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($index = $total)">
         <xsl:call-template name="repeatable">
            <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="$index" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Then, you can wrap the `xsl:call-template` in an `xsl:variable` to capture that value, then output it

```
<xsl:variable name="result">
   <xsl:call-template name="repeatable" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$result" />
```

This would output `10` in this case.

Comment: "*This would output `10` in this case.*" Is there a case where it would output anything else?